# Улучшение конструкции if-else при валидации значений

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Думаю, конструкцию `if-else` можно улучшить, но не могу придумать как. Что можно сделать?

```
if ((limit != null && !limit.matches("^-?\\d+$") && !limit.equals("")) 
        || (length != null && !length.matches("^-?\\d+$") && !length.equals(""))
        || (limit != null && limit.matches("^-?\\d+$") && Integer.parseInt(limit) < 0)
        || (length != null && length.matches("^-?\\d+$") && Integer.parseInt(length) < 0))
{
    resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
}
else
{
    resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(TextFileAPI.TextFileQuery(q, limit, length, appPath));
}
```

Comment: как вариант - вынести все проверки из этого if'а в отдельный метод, и передавать limit в условии, метод возвращает булевое, если true - то
`resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST); `
else оставляете.

Answer (score 1):

Код проверки валидности для `limit` и `length` одинаков, так что можно его вынести в отдельный метод и вызывать для каждого значения.

Допустимыми значениями, судя по коду, являются `null`, пустая строка, а также неотрицательные `Integer`.

В итоге получается так. Метод проверки:

```
private static boolean isCorrect(String value)
{
    return (value == null || value.equals("") ||
            (value.matches("^\\d+$") && Integer.parseInt(value) >= 0));
}
```

Его использование:

```
if (isCorrect(limit) && isCorrect(length))
{
    //correct data handling
}
else
{
    //incorrect data handling
}
```

---

Дабы при обработке больших чисел, не входящих в `Integer` (например, 3 миллиарда), метод `isCorrect` не "падал" с `NumberFormatException`, стоит несколько усложнить код:

```
private static boolean isCorrect(String value)
{
    if (value == null || value.equals(""))
    {
        return true;
    }
    boolean isCorrect = false;
    try
    {
        isCorrect = Integer.parseInt(value) >= 0;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
    return isCorrect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант без функции, практически ваш вариант, но 4 сокращено в 2.

   ```
   //!limit.equals("") медленно, есть метод isEmpty (size == 0 => true)
   //Проверка на принадлежность к только числовому ряду, я так понел? медленно...
   if(((limit != null && !limit.matches("^-?\\d+$")) && (!limit.equals("") || Integer.parseInt(limit) < 0)) ||
     ((length != null && !length.matches("^-?\\d+$") && (!length.equals("")) || Integer.parseInt(length) < 0))){
       //Два метода слиты в один
       resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
   }else {
       resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
       resp.getWriter().write(TextFileAPI.TextFileQuery(q, limit, length, appPath));

   }
   ```
2. Вариант, функция (если я правильно понел логику, если нет то это легко исправляется)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String limit = "5";
       String length = "5";

       //!limit.equals("") медленно, есть метод isEmpty (size == 0 => true)
       if(isCorr(limit) || isCorr(length)){
           //Два метода слиты в один
           resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
       }else {
           resp.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
           resp.getWriter().write(TextFileAPI.TextFileQuery(q, limit, length, appPath));

       }

   }

   private static boolean isCorr(String str){
       if(str != null && !str.matches("^-?\\d+$") && !str.equals("")){

           try{
               return Integer.parseInt(str) >= 0;
           }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           }
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

все таки ответ напишу, хоть уже и время прошло.. Сразу скажу мне помогали.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

interface Func {
  void apply(int a, String b);
}

class B {
  void b0(int a, String b) {
    out.println("b0");
  }

  void b1(int a, String b) {
    out.println("b1");
  }
}

class D0 implements Func {
  public void apply(int a, String b) {
    out.println("d0");
  }
}

public class Sample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sample().execute(5, "Hello, world!");
  }

  Func[] functions;

  void a0(int a, String b) {
    out.println("a0: a=" + a + ", b=" + b);
  }

  static void a1(int a, String b) {
    out.println("a1");
  }

  Sample() {
    // разные способы объявления функций
    B beta = new B(); // обычный класс
    Func c0 = (a, b) -> out.println("c0"); // lambda
    Func c1 = new Func() { // анонимный класс
      public void apply(int a, String b) {
        out.println("a1");
      }
    };
    Func d0 = new D0(); // обычный класс
    functions = new Func[]{
        this::a0, // сылка на метод
        Sample::a1, // сылка на метод
        beta::b0, // сылка на метод
        beta::b1, // сылка на метод
        c0,
        c1,
        d0,
        (a, b) -> out.println("d1"), // lambda
    };
  }

  void execute(int a, String b) {
    for (Func f: functions) {
      f.apply(a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

... это максимально близко к тому что я предлагал. Извините если что не так.

Answer (score -2):

простой пример и я думаю вы поймете как применить к вашему коду:

```
    var t_event={};
     t_event[0]=function(){return;};
     t_event[1]=function(a,b){ return console.log(a*b);},
     test;

     function test(_t,_event,_a,_b){
         return _event[(!(_t === 1))+0](_a,_b);
     };
     test(0,t_event,3,5);
```

можно делать переход по "индексу" [0/1] в разных вариантах, это и будет отработка условия, просто проверки как таковой нет, по результату предыдущего действия (false/true) вы сразу "проваливаетесь" через индекс в нужную функцию или событие...

Comment: вы знаете, что Java и JavaScript совершенно разные языки?

Comment: да в курсе.. я вам написал пример, который по аналогии применил даже в bash...

Comment: Вот и перепишите код на java. В java нет функций.

Comment: Да и в bash такое:) Ха-ха:)

Comment: постараюсь попозже написать на Java. Просто займет время, но напишу...обязательно.

Comment: дело не в bash а в идее..